# Python custom modules - error with example code

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am reading the book "*Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner (3rd edition)*".  I am in the chapter introducing custom modules and I believe this may be an error in the coding in the book, because I have checked it 5 or 6 times and matched it exactly.

First we have a custom module *games.py*

```
class Player(object):
    """ A player for a game. """
    def __init__(self, name, score = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score

    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + ":\t" + str(self.score)
        return rep

def ask_yes_no(question):
    """ Ask a yes or no question. """
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question, low, high):
    """ Ask for a number within a range """
    response = None
    while response not in range (low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("You ran this module directly (and did not 'import' it).")
    input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

And now the *SimpleGame.py*

```
import games, random


print("Welcome to the world's simplest game!\n")

again = None
while again != "n":
    players = []

num = games.ask_number(question = "How many players? (2 - 5): ", low = 2, high = 5)
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("Player name: ")
        score = random.randrange(100) + 1
        player = games.Player(name, score)
        players.append(player)

    print("\nHere are the game results:")
    for player in players:
        print(player)

    again = games.ask_yes_no("\nDo you want to play again? (y/n): ")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

So this is exactly how the code appears in the book.  When I run the program I get the error `IndentationError` at `for i in range(num):`.  I expected this would happen so I changed it and removed 1 tab or 4 spaces in front of each line from `for i in range(num)` to `again = games.ask_yes_no("\nDo you want to play again? (y/n): ")`.

After this the output is `"Welcome to the world's simplest game!"` and that's it.

**I was wondering if someone could let me know why this is happening?**

Also, the `import games` module, is recognized in Eclipse after I added the path to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: your indentation looks wrong ... i think `num=...` needs more indent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have this book myself.  And yes, it is a typo.  Here is how to fix it:

```
# SimpleGame.py
import games, random


print("Welcome to the world's simplest game!\n")

again = None
while again != "n":
    players = []

    num = games.ask_number(question = "How many players? (2 - 5): ", low = 2, high = 5)
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("Player name: ")
        score = random.randrange(100) + 1
        player = games.Player(name, score)
        players.append(player)

    print("\nHere are the game results:")
    for player in players:
        print(player)

    again = games.ask_yes_no("\nDo you want to play again? (y/n): ")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

All I did was indent `num` 4 spaces and lined it up with the first for-loop.

Comment: Oh, thank you!  I should have done this, but I drove myself insane going over the code repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
again = None
while again != "n":
    players = []
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is exactly the way it's printed in the book, the book does have an error.

You've got these two lines:

```
num = games.ask_number(question = "How many players? (2 - 5): ", low = 2, high = 5)
    for i in range(num):
```

The second one is more indented than the first. That's only legal if the first one is a block-introducer like a `for` or `while` or `if`. Since it's not, this is an `IndentationError`. And that's exactly what Python is telling you.

(It's possible that you've copied things wrong. It's also possible that you're mixing tabs and spaces, so it actually looks right in your editor, but it looks wrong to Python. But if neither of those is true, the book is wrong.)

So, you attempted to fix it by dedenting everything from that `for` loop on.

But when you do that, only one line is still left under the `while` loop:

```
while again != "n":
    players = []
```

There's nothing that can possibly change `again` to `"n"`, so this will just spin forever, doing nothing, and not moving on to the rest of the program.

So, what you probably want to do is to *indent* the `num = …` line to the same level as the `for i…` line, so both of them (and all the stuff after) ends up inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you.  I realize now it is easy to miss even the most simple of errors.

Comment: @mccdlibby: The fact that there are two different ways it could be fixed—both of which compile, but one is right, while the other just leads to a useless infinite loop—is exactly why Python can't fix it for you, and gives you an error message to debug.